# grey down google maps on background, map interaction thru rectangle area

Tags: css, google-maps

I have a fullscreen google maps web page similar to this http://wadehammes.com/dewey-beach/, now how can I grey down the whole area (map) except for a rectangle div-container?

I want to create the cool effect of looking the map "through a window", where the "window" is a div-rectangle, and also be able to interact with the map only on the area inside the rectangle (div-container).

I imagine CSS should do that, am I wrong? Any idea how to do that?

I hope I expressed well myself
Thanks

Comment: It seems like one way would be to grey out the background map, then overlay another map the size of the window that registers to the exact same location as the background, with no "greying" in the upper map.

Comment: I thought about it but performance can be a downside specially because both maps need to be synchronized in order to reflects the interaction in both maps like this: http://maps.forum.nu/gm_maps_in_sync.html

Comment: Well, you could create an overlay of DIVs or an overlay image with a transparent block, and then use Javascript to transfer the mouse clicks underneath.

Comment: An example using DIVs: http://jsfiddle.net/Pxvfu/1/ (Tested in Chrome and FF 7.) Note, this is just a demonstration; for instance, the height is not 100%. But you get the idea.

Comment: @lito actually it's not about performance, but Google Map's events. We have bounds_change but no "mousemove" event, so that's the best behavior you could achieve. Anyway see my response, seems pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you will need two maps, because Google doesn't let you apply a style to "just a part" of the map. So you'll have two versions: black & white, and color map. Then with CSS you hack the position one inside the other, and with JS you add support for user dragging. If you need to add extra things such as markers, or click actions, just remember to bind those events to both created maps: `map` & `other`. Check the [demo I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/tomasdev/2eYXE/).

I've created this little demo in 10 mins, just copy-paste and it will work. The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Map Loop</title>
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#map-container{
    height:400px; /* map height */
    position:relative;
    width:500px; /* map width */
}
#map-canvas{
    height:400px; /* map height */
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
    width:500px; /* map width */
}
.loop{
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;top:100px;left:150px; /* offset in map view */
    width:200px;
}
#map-canvas2{
    height:400px; /* map height */
    margin:-100px 0 0 -150px; /* opposite to top and left in .loop */
    width:500px; /* map width */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div class="loop">
        <div id="map-canvas2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  // 2 = color
  // 1 = b&w
  var mapDiv = $('#map-canvas2')[0];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    disableDefaultUI: true, /* we dont need UI in the loop */
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var other = $('#map-canvas')[0];

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(other, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
      stylers: [{ saturation: -100 }]
    }]
  });

  // flag to prevent buggy behavior
  var BLACK_WHITE_MAP = false;
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function() {
    BLACK_WHITE_MAP = false;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'mousedown', function() {
    BLACK_WHITE_MAP = true;
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    !BLACK_WHITE_MAP && map2.setCenter(this.getCenter());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    BLACK_WHITE_MAP && map.setCenter(this.getCenter());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```